# In Python, why does the exact same line of code fail the first time and succeed the second time?

Tags: python

Here's my code exactly as it appears (I'm working on a Numerical Analysis homework problem):

```
import integration as I
from math import *
import numpy as np

problem = 4

<snip/>

elif problem == 4:

    h = 0.001
    X = np.linspace(0,1, 1//h+2)

    def f(x):
        if x==0 or x==1:
            return 0
        try:
            return x**3/( (1-x)**5 * (e**(x/(1-x))-1) )
        except OverflowError:
            return 0

    try:
        Y = list(map(f,X))
    except:
        print("That failed.")
        Y = list(map(f,X))

    print("Integral: %s"%I.Simpsons_L(Y, h))
```

Here's the output to shell:

```
>>> 
That failed.
Integral: 6.49393940227
>>>
```

If I don't have the `except` clause in there, then this is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<snip/>", line 150, in <module>
    Y = list(map(f,X))
  File "<snip/>", line 145, in f
    return x**3/( (1-x)**5 * (e**(x/(1-x))-1) )
  File "C:\Python33\lib\idlelib\PyShell.py", line 60, in idle_showwarning
    file.write(warnings.formatwarning(message, category, filename,
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'
```

**Edit 1**

If I run my program from the command line, this is what I get:

```
NA_homework3problems.py:145: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars
  return x**3/( (1-x)**5 * (e**(x/(1-x))-1) )
```

---

Clearly, I have a workaround for my problem, so that's not why I'm asking this question. I'm asking why there's a problem in the first place. I am literally executing the same functions twice, and it works the second time but not the first. Also, this issue doesn't come up if I only have `map` by itself, and if I attempt to use `list` on the same map twice, the second one is empty, which I think is by design. So, **what's going on here?**

Comment: **Anything** could be happening. Consider not catching the exception, or logging its stack trace, to at least get an idea of what's going on here.

Comment: What exception are you actually getting?

Comment: From the zen of python: errors should never pass silently... I.e. let's see the exception.

Comment: @JeffSheffield: I had already seen the error in IDLE's shell, so it didn't occur to me to include the traceback in the question.

Comment: Well, now IDLE is trying to show you a warning about something, but it can't for some reason (its internal `file` is `None`, but no indication why). Try running your program without IDLE and see if you get a better error message.

Comment: @GregHewgill: Updated. Seems to be a runtime overflow error.

Answer (score 3):

Something you've done previously has replaced the `file` reference in pyshell with `None`

During your first run through the map, an exception and **[Warning](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/warnings.html)** is being generated

eg

```
RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars
```

The exception you are seeing is due to the attempt to print this warning failing.

The normal way warnings work is that once you've been alerted the warning is silenced for the remainder of the session

The second run also triggers the overflow, but since the warning is suppressed it doesn't try to print the error and so the pyshell error is also not encountered

You should look through your code and figure out what you are doing that's blowing away the `file` variable in pyshell

Comment: Ah, interesting. But `file` doesn't appear anywhere in my code, and the code I've pasted in my question is all that gets executed (minus a few unused-here import statements). The function `Simpsons_L` (which I wrote) also doesn't do anything with `file`. I would guess it has something to do with numpy's internal code.

Comment: It's definitely numpy's fault. `import numpy; 1/numpy.float64(0)` will throw the error I got.

Answer (score 0):

I did some more hunting and pinned down what causes the problem. Somehow, it is not my code, but rather numpy's. The following lines of code are sufficient to throw the error the first time but not the second.

```
>>> import numpy
>>> 1/numpy.float64(0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#84>", line 1, in <module>
    1/numpy.float64(0)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\idlelib\PyShell.py", line 64, in idle_showwarning
    file.write(warnings.formatwarning(message, category, filename,
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'
>>> 1/numpy.float64(0)
inf
```

Somehow, `sys.__stderr__` gets set to `None`. I have submitted a bug report for this issue: [#5289](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/5289). Hopefully it'll be fixed soon.